# How to compute a weighted loop?

Tags: python, loops, weighted

This is a portion of my data frame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'IBI_msec': [652, 618, 654],
    'rate': [92.02, 97.09, 91.74]
})
```

I need to compute a loop that enables me to compute this logic:

- if `652 > 500`, then `bin = 92.02`, and the remaining `(652 - 500)` goes to the next bin;
- because the `bin2` contains the `152`, remaining from the previous
  row, only `348` msec from `618` are needed. In that case, a weighted average is needed: `((152*92.02) + (348*97.09)) / 500` which gives `95.55`.
- (I don't expect to have IBI values under 500 in the data).

[image]

The final result should be something like this:

```
  IBI_msec    rate   bins
0      652   92.02  92.02
1      618   97.09  95.55
2      654   91.74  94.63
```

Comment: What should happen if the first value was 350 for example (or any value under 500) ? Or are you sure all values are above 500 ?

Comment: I apologize for not mentioning it earlier. I deleted numbers less than 500 because they are considered noise.

Comment: Ok; better update you question to mention that then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you want: that said, there will be a problem if (when) remainder goes over 500, so you should complete your rules to deal with that case.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'IBI_msec': [652, 618, 654],
    'rate': [92.02, 97.09, 91.74]
})

bins = []
remainder = 0
for i in range(len(df)):
    if i == 0:
        bins.append(df['rate'][0])
        fill = 500
    else:
        fill = 500 - remainder
        bins.append(round((remainder*df['rate'][i-1]+fill*df['rate'][i])/500,2))
    remainder = df['IBI_msec'][i] - fill
    
print(bins)
# [92.02, 95.55, 94.63]
```